# ROW_NUMBER() not sequencing records correctly

Tags: java, sql, oracle, row-number

I had to copy the data from oracle tables to files.

I have a join query which fetches 800k records so i used row_number() function along with order by clause to generate 4 files containing 200k each.

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by FILE_KEY desc ) rn,
        FILE_KEY, ROUTING_NO, INTLROUT_TYPE, ABBR_COUNTRY_CODE_2D, HO_CATALOG_NO 
    FROM BANK_INTL_ROUT_TBL rout, BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL loc 
    WHERE loc.CATALOG_NO = rout.FILE_KEY) 
WHERE rn BETWEEN start AND end;
```

Parameters:

```
For 1st File  : start =1 ,end = 200000
For 2nd File  : start =200001 ,end = 400000
For 3rd File  : start =400001 ,end = 600000
For 4th File  : start =600001 ,end = 800000
```

But when i checked last 10 row using this query in sql query browser and last 10 rows of file are different that is sequence is different in file and sql query browser.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(  order by FILE_KEY desc ) rn,
        FILE_KEY,ROUTING_NO,INTLROUT_TYPE,ABBR_COUNTRY_CODE_2D,HO_CATALOG_NO 
    FROM BANK_INTL_ROUT_TBL rout, BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL loc 
    WHERE loc.CATALOG_NO=rout.FILE_KEY) 
WHERE rn BETWEEN 709990 AND 80000;
```

Comment: Which table is the master and which is the details ? If BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL is the details then is it possible that the same FILE_KEY will be more than once in the resultset ?

Comment: yes BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL  is details and FILE_KEY is more than once

Comment: Without an `order by` clause on the query, the rows written to the file may be in an order different from the `row_number()` order. So you last query, when corrected to use a unique key, **may not** give you the last ten rows of the file, but just ten rows that exist somewhere in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be because you have something like this

```
row_number file_key 
799998     same_number
799999     same_number
800000     same_number
800001     same_number
800002     same_number
800003     same_number
800004     same_number
```

because you order by file_key.

How do you observed that are different data? from your other columns. So, you can use:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by FILE_KEY desc, ROUTING_NO, INTLROUT_TYPE, ABBR_COUNTRY_CODE_2D, HO_CATALOG_NO ) rn
```

Or(second cause), your base table had been changen between your querys.

**UDPDATE**: you can use the `use_hash` hint to speed up your query. 5 hours is too much for this query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  /*+use_hash(rout loc)*/
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by FILE_KEY desc, ROUTING_NO, INTLROUT_TYPE, ABBR_COUNTRY_CODE_2D, HO_CATALOG_NO ) rn,
        FILE_KEY, ROUTING_NO, INTLROUT_TYPE, ABBR_COUNTRY_CODE_2D, HO_CATALOG_NO 
    FROM BANK_INTL_ROUT_TBL rout, BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL loc 
    WHERE loc.CATALOG_NO = rout.FILE_KEY) 
WHERE rn BETWEEN start AND end;
```

Comment: Thanks Florin Ghita ,will check this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Florin and Shannon ,I used this query and instead of checking the sequence I created a class for checking that if there are any duplicated records in it,but there were none.

Answer (score 1):

In the over clause, order by a unique field in BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by loc.**LOC_KEY** desc ) rn,
        FILE_KEY, ROUTING_NO, INTLROUT_TYPE, ABBR_COUNTRY_CODE_2D, HO_CATALOG_NO 
    FROM BANK_INTL_ROUT_TBL rout, BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL loc 
    WHERE loc.CATALOG_NO = rout.FILE_KEY) 
WHERE rn BETWEEN start AND end
ORDER BY rn;
```

**UPDATE**: according to @Shannon Severance comment
add the order by clause

Comment: Hi A.B,I used CATALOG_NO which is the BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL primary key but its shows same last 10 record sequence as FILE_KEY in query browser,So will changing to CATALOG_NO generate correct and consistent row sequence in files?

Comment: @neel.1708 have you tried to generate the 4 files with my query, and then verify?

Comment: ok ,It takes almost 5hrs to generate the files hence i wanted to confirm before that ,ok will check after generating file :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have disk to spare on your Oracle installation (which you should!), then instead of running the inner query 4 times it may end up being faster to do the following

```
CREATE TABLE bank_data
NOLOGGING
PARALLEL 4
AS SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by FILE_KEY desc ) rn,
    FILE_KEY, ROUTING_NO, INTLROUT_TYPE, ABBR_COUNTRY_CODE_2D, HO_CATALOG_NO 
FROM BANK_INTL_ROUT_TBL rout, BANK_INTL_LOC_TBL loc 
WHERE loc.CATALOG_NO = rout.FILE_KEY);
```

The amount of parallelism to use (the number `4` in my example here) will depend on how much concurrent work your database can handle, mostly dependent on the number of CPUs.

After that has finished, (which should take noticably less than 5 hours!) you can then run simple selects on the `bank_dump` table to pull the records you desire

```
SELECT *
FROM bank_dump
where rn < 200000
```

for your first data set, for example.